# Multiple lookups in a Django view

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I have this models.py:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    name= models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Work(models.Model):
    creator = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name = 'creator')

class Event(models.Model):
    repertoire = models.ManyToManyField(Work, blank=True)
```

Now, in my template I'd like to show all the events containing the works which is present in the `repertoire` field of an event for a specific creator. So:

views.py:

```
context['events'] = Event.objects.filter(repertoire__work__creator_id=1) # why is this not possible?
```

The event 'Great event' has in repertoire:

- song 1, by John
- song 2, by James
- song 3, by Jonathan

In John, James, and Jonathan's profile page I want to show the Great event details, because they have one of their piece performed in that date.

Comment: I think the correct query would be `Event.objects.filter(repertoire__creator_id=1)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by @Sajad, the correct code is `Event.objects.filter(repertoire__creator_id=1)` .